# specs run on an extracted Rails::Engine do not initialize/restore DB to pristine state as before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

I've recently extracted a module to a `Rails::Engine` gem that contains a "dummy application" for running the tests on.  `rake spec` now behaves differently, and is causing some specs to fail.

First, running `rake spec --trace` in the gem directory no longer causes this long invocation chain:

```
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute spec
```

Instead just calling:

```
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Execute spec
```

I don't see any code in RSpec::Core::RakeTask that does DB initialization, so this must be a Rails function added by the Rakefile in a Rails root directory.

I considered dealing with that by adding this:

```
task :my_spec do
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
  Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
  Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
  ENV['SCHEMA'] = '/Users/me/sandbox/my_app/db/schema.rb'
  Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke
  Rake::Task['spec'].invoke
end
```

But none of these tasks are loaded by the Rakefile in the gem's root.

How can I get `rake spec` to initialize the test DB from this directory?

Second, rspec is no longer clearing the DB in between tests, so tests that relied on a pristine DB state are now failing.  Perhaps this means I'm writing my tests wrong, but I have considered the "blank slate" idea for tests to be a helpful one when understand test output.

How can I get `rake spec` to clear the DB in between tests as it does for a normal Rails app?